# Endless scrolling when showing data from server in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, android-volley

I have a image app. It load images from server and database. When user click on specific button app send a request with post data(Category) to server using volley.
Server than get post variable and fetch data from database and send data as a json response. Then i show images in `recyclerview`.

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    imagelist = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ImageAdapter(DJPhotos.this, imagelist);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    public void getJsonResponsePost() {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("table", table);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, script, json,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    imagelist.clear();
                    JSONArray heroArray = null;
                    try {
                        heroArray = response.getJSONArray("item");
                        for (int i = 0; i < heroArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = heroArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Photos photos = new Photos();
                            photos.setUrl(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                            photos.setThumb(jsonObject.getString("thumb"));
                            imagelist.add(photos);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

        }
    });
    jsonObjectRequest.setTag(REQ_TAG);
    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

My **PHP** script -

```
 $sql = "select * from $table  WHERE (dp='1') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
 $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 $post_data_array = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
         $img     = $row['image'];
         $post_data_array[] = array(
                 'image' => $image
            );
 $post_data = json_encode(array('item' => $post_data_array));
 echo $post_data;
```

There are many images in database and if i not set limit then server takes time to fetch data. It make app slow .
I have a website where i use pagination. In pagination i use LIMIT to show data.
Now i want that when user click on button only first 10 images from database get load and after user scroll the `recyclerview` another 10 images should load and continue.

I know it can be done with `AsyncTask`, but i don't find any script that match with my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know it can be done with AsyncTask

This is the worst approach ever don't do it.

Android now provides a **native paging Library** as part of the **Android architecture components**, use that read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/). Before this approach people used to do it using `onScrollChangedListener` set to the recycler view you can still use that but the paging library is recommended.

Comment: how to implement it ?

Comment: To use paging library in android as you've suggested here, should the server side page be paginated too. For ex: If I am getting 700+ data as a list and I'm passing only 2 params: Token and UserId. Then, will the paging library work. Or the Server php page must be paginated?

Comment: Without backend paging, the paging library of android is waste from the network?

Comment: ideally, the experience will be smooth but in case you have to do it locally you will need to download all 700+ results( waiting time increase in the app as the UI is blocked) and locally load the items, WHICH IS NOT RECOMMENDED

Answer (score 0):

On the adapter

create an interface like this for e.g.

```
public interface OnFetchMoreRequested {
    void fetchMore();
}
```

then onBindViewHolder you can trigger that interface based on ur condition for e.g.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecipeViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(position == imagelist.size() - 1 && onFetchMoreRequested != null){
        onFetchMoreRequested.fetchMore();
    }
    ... rest of the code
}
```

also create a setter and a field for `OnFetchMoreRequested` interface

```
OnFetchMoreRequested onFetchMoreRequested = null;

public void setOnFetchMoreRequested(OnFetchMoreRequested onFetchMoreRequested){
    this.onFetchMoreRequested = onFetchMoreRequested;
}
```

On the activity

```
adapter.setOnFetchMoreRequested(new OnFetchMoreRequested() {
    @Override
    void fetchMore(){
        ... Go ahead and call your server 
    }
});
```